# SHould the "safe" tag exist?

Tags: discussion, tags

There are currently 6 questions using the [safe](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/safe) tag, including one of my own. Should this tag even exists? Does it have value on its own? I was going to simply remove it from each of those questions but thought it might be best to get other opinions first.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't see that it adds anything. Burninate away.